# "Set as contact" ruins images in editing pane

Tags: gallery, google-photos

I just bought my girlfriend a Zenfone 2 500ML, and I have to say I am really impressed about it. There are only an issue I would like to know if it is a known problem or not.

When I want to set an image as a contact picture, I select a photo through Google Photos (because Gallery crashes every time, don't know why and if it is related), the photo editing app appears. App itself is ok, but the image is "damaged", because it has purple dots all over the photo (like in this sample)

[image: These pixels appears only in this pane and after saving]

If I move the photo, dots change place, so I think it is all related to a software bug on image resizing maybe, or thumbnail creation. However, once I accept my changes, photo is set correctly to the contact, and it is perfect with no issues. The only small problem is in contact thumbnail that seems damaged, but the photo itself is intact.

If I try to set it as lockscreen, or send it on Whatsapp, it works like a charm, even if I apply filters of any kind.

I would like to know if someone had this problem, and mainly know if it is purely a software bug (so I will wait for an update) or there is something more serious (and how to fix it, in case it is).